# Troubles with MVVM binding

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, mvvm, ado.net

I am new to mvvm, basicaly its my first attempt. At now I have a WPF window, ado.net to connect to my database, and wcf service to make connection between viewmodel and database. The problem is that I cant add data from my view to database.
here some code
My wcf methods:

```
[OperationContract]
    public void ManageOrder(Order order, EntityState state)
    {
        using (var context = new SvLaserEntities())
        {
            context.Attach(order);
            context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(order, state);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
    [OperationContract]
    public void ManageClient(Client client, EntityState state)
    {
        using (var context = new SvLaserEntities())
        {
            context.Attach(client);
            context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(client, state);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

A command for binding to button:

```
public ICommand AddClient
    {
        get
        {
            if ((addClient == null) && (CurrentClient != null))
            {
                addClient = new RelayCommand(() => this.client.ManageClientAsync(CurrentClient, EntityState.Added));
            }
            return addClient;
        }
    }
```

And xaml code for one of textboxes:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" 
                         Margin="469,50,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                         VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160"
                         Text="{Binding CurrentClient.Name, Mode=Default, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         />
```

Direct problem is when I am filling the textboxes and clicking to add them, I am catching null reference exception here, at client parameter:

```
public void ManageClient(Client client, EntityState state)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it the client or the entity state that is null? Can you post your client class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your xaml change the

Mode attribute in binding to TWOway like

```
   <TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentClient.Name, Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

please make sure that INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented in viewmodel and model

Comment: Tried, still getting same exception :/ The CurrentClient property is not filling with data the typed in textbox :( Its just null when its sending to database.

Comment: have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged  in the viewmodel and model

Comment: Yes I did. But onlu in viewmodel. Fro model I use ado.net built model.